# How to intersect CAShapeLayers in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer, cgrect

I have a plus (+) sign that's currently colored in blue but I would like to make it transparent so that the user can see the background. The plus layer is added to a bigger view. Setting the plus layer to `clear` color doesn't solve the problem.

```
class AddButtonView: UIView {
    ...

    private func setupPlusLayer() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: plusButton.frame.midX, y: plusButton.frame.midY-20))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: plusButton.frame.midX, y: plusButton.frame.midY+20))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: plusButton.frame.midX-20, y: plusButton.frame.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: plusButton.frame.midX+20, y: plusButton.frame.midY))
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4

        // Add that `CAShapeLayer` to your view's layer:
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I make the plus sign transparent?

Comment: What is plus button layer?  Maybe it should be self.layer add shapelayer

Comment: @agibson007 thanks, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that, by:

1. create circle `CAShapeLayer` (`circleShape`);
2. create inverted mask layer (`inverted`) with same color as `circleShape`. For this case you need a `CGMutablePath` with exactly the same circle path and the plus path. Also, don't forget to set `inverted.fillRule = .evenOdd`;
3. than you need a layer with transparent plus sign only (`plusShape`);
4. add `circleShape` as a sublayer to view's layer;
5. setup mask: `circleShape.mask = inverted`;
6. add `plusShape` as a sublayer to view's layer.

That's it! Now you have transparent plus sing. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using a .png image with the + made transparent it will work fine and you will not need to draw the plus.

Comment: It would be really cool to be able to draw the plus programmatically to save space and make the app resolution-proof.

Comment: it will be cool, but it's a lot of work whiteout without that great outcome in my opinion.